# Alienware 17 R2 No sound

Tags: 16.04, sound, alienware

Just installed ubuntu 16 on my alienware 17 R2, and there are no sound. I have tried to unmuted the card from alsamixer. but i think that the hdmi card is set as default. Is it any way to fix this?

#### `lspci -nnk | grep -A3 -Fe '[0403]'` output:

```
00:03.0 Audio device [0403]: Intel Corporation Xeon E3-1200 v3/4th Gen Core Processor HD Audio Controller [8086:0c0c] (rev 06)
    Subsystem: Dell Xeon E3-1200 v3/4th Gen Core Processor HD Audio Controller [1028:0688]
    Kernel driver in use: snd_hda_intel
    Kernel modules: snd_hda_intel

00:1b.0 Audio device [0403]: Intel Corporation 8 Series/C220 Series Chipset High Definition Audio Controller [8086:8c20] (rev 05)
    Subsystem: Dell 8 Series/C220 Series Chipset High Definition Audio Controller [1028:0688]
    Kernel driver in use: snd_hda_intel
    Kernel modules: snd_hda_intel
```

#### `aplay -l` output:

```
**** List of PLAYBACK Hardware Devices ****
card 0: HDMI [HDA Intel HDMI], device 3: HDMI 0 [HDMI 0]
  Subdevices: 1/1
  Subdevice #0: subdevice #0

card 0: HDMI [HDA Intel HDMI], device 7: HDMI 1 [HDMI 1]
  Subdevices: 1/1
  Subdevice #0: subdevice #0

card 0: HDMI [HDA Intel HDMI], device 8: HDMI 2 [HDMI 2]
  Subdevices: 1/1
  Subdevice #0: subdevice #0

card 1: PCH [HDA Intel PCH], device 0: CA0132 Analog [CA0132 Analog]
  Subdevices: 1/1
  Subdevice #0: subdevice #0
```

#### `pactl list short sinks` output:

```
0   alsa_output.pci-0000_00_03.0.hdmi-stereo    module-alsa-card.c  s16le 2ch 44100Hz   SUSPENDED

1   alsa_output.pci-0000_00_1b.0.analog-stereo  module-alsa-card.c  s16le 2ch 44100Hz   SUSPENDED
```

#### `setpci -vD -s 01:00.0 0x488.l=0x2000000:0x2000000` output:

```
0000:01:00.0 @488 ffffffff->(02000000:02000000)->ffffffff
```

Comment: Could you please [edit] your question to include the output of the terminal commands `lspci -nnk | grep -A3 -Fe '[0403]'`, `aplay -l`, and `pactl list short sinks`? Please also make sure that the relevant audio channels in `alsamixer` (terminal) or `gnome-alsamixer` (GUI) have their volume turned up and aren’t muted. Thanks.

Comment: Copy and paste this into your terminal `setpci -vD -s 01:00.0 0x488.l=0x2000000:0x2000000` and report the output please.

Answer (score 1):

The Alienware line comes with high-end Nvidia Graphics.

You need to install Nvidia proprietary drivers in order to have the full functionality and performance.

Comment: That's an older laptop with low-end nVidia Graphics which should have support built into current Nouveau Graphics Drivers by this time.

Answer (score 1):

I think it is a sound driver issue,

try this: although there isnt a beaver update file yet. but any ubuntu up to 17.10 should work. these are the drivers that are updated daily.

https://launchpad.net/~ubuntu-audio-dev/+archive/ubuntu/alsa-daily