# Installed Ubuntu on Alienware but no sound

Tags: sound, pulseaudio, alsa, alienware

Installed Ubuntu 21.04 on Alienware Area-51 R2 desktop. There was no sound. I searched all over internet for solution. Tried pavucontrol and alsamixer, but didn't work. After adding "options snd-hda-intel model=auto" to alsa-base.conf file, now I am getting sound coming out of speaker, but it is barely audible! I have turned volume all the way up but all I am getting is volume output at whisper level. I think the codec is Creative CA0132.
Here is the alsa info: http://alsa-project.org/db/?f=c3178e47c917390d96f062189ef0f1f7e9ae00b5

I am new to linux and I have absolute no idea how to fix this. Please help!

Comment: You did not check the forum, did you? [Click](https://askubuntu.com/questions/999752/alienware-17-r2-no-sound)

Answer (score 0):

In `etc/modprobe.d/alsa-base.conf`, try this line instead of the one you mentioned:

```
options snd-hda-intel index=0 model=alienware
```

If even this did not help, you can try to run this script I found somewhere in the internet (probably a dead forum), which worked for my Alienware 17 R3, as root:

```
#!/bin/sh

# These lines override BIOS pin mapping:
echo 0x0b 0x90174010 > /sys/class/sound/hwC0D0/user_pin_configs
echo 0x0c 0x014580f0 > /sys/class/sound/hwC0D0/user_pin_configs
echo 0x0d 0x014570f0 > /sys/class/sound/hwC0D0/user_pin_configs
echo 0x0e 0x01c530f0 > /sys/class/sound/hwC0D0/user_pin_configs
echo 0x0f 0x0221401f > /sys/class/sound/hwC0D0/user_pin_configs
echo 0x10 0x02216011 > /sys/class/sound/hwC0D0/user_pin_configs
echo 0x11 0x02012014 > /sys/class/sound/hwC0D0/user_pin_configs
echo 0x12 0x37a791f0 > /sys/class/sound/hwC0D0/user_pin_configs
echo 0x13 0x908700f0 > /sys/class/sound/hwC0D0/user_pin_configs
echo 0x18 0x500000f0 > /sys/class/sound/hwC0D0/user_pin_configs

# This one kills pulseaudio (which automatically reboots) and makes
# changes persistent.

pulseaudio -k && echo 1 > /sys/class/sound/hwC0D0/reconfig
```

Now you can run `alsamixer` in the terminal, move with your directional arrows to the right, until you find a second option screen with the unchecked "HP/speaker Auto Detect". You can check it by pressing `m` key.

Then, just to be sure, power off your PC and turn it on again (I read that reboot could be not enough for some reasons, and at least for my PC, I found it to be true).

There could be some oddities, like that if you turn on your PC with headpones plugged in, it may use external speaker, and if you unplug them, external speaker could become mute (because system is trying to play sound out of your hearphones, which are indeed unplugged). The same with microphone.

**WARNING: As well as this script may fix all of your problem, it could make your sound not to work anymore at all.**

If it does, then just run:

```
sudo apt purge pulseaudio* alsamixer*
```

and reinstall the uninstalled packages again, then reboot (or power off/on) and your default sound configuration should be recreated by scratch. So you can at least add some line to alsa-base.conf and get speaker to work.

**Please note:** for correct mic configuration, I also had to remove noise from my mic by following this video: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=DHcd-GXgnDM

Which suggested to run this line:

```
wget -qO - https://bit.ly/2mBJSJo | sudo bash && pulseaudio -k
```

If for some reasons that video goes offline or the file in bitly becomes unavaliable, it may useful to know that it was inspired by this answer: [Realtime noise-removal with PulseAudio?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/18958/realtime-noise-removal-with-pulseaudio)